# Java Graphics Composite inconsistencies

Tags: java, swing, graphics, composite

So I have been going through the java tutorials however when testing with the AlphaComposite class as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html when I go to implement them the different attributes seem to be mixed up. For instance AlphaComposite.Clear and AlphaComposite.SrcOut appear to be switched and AlphaComposite.SrcIn appears to remove the non-overlapping src pixels but not the non-overlapping destination pixels. Here is the code I am testing with.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TEST extends JFrame{
    public static int width = 1200;
    public static int height = 1200;

    public TEST(String title) {
        super(title);
        this.setContentPane(new Drawer());
        this.setSize(width,height);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class Drawer extends JPanel{
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(500,500,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();

            graphics.setColor(Color.red);
            graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
            graphics.setColor(Color.gray);
            graphics.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
            graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcIn);

            graphics.setColor(Color.blue);
            graphics.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);


            graphics.dispose();
            g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TEST("HI");
    }
}
```

So am I implementing the composite incorrectly or is there something else wrong here?

Comment: `graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcIn);` has an effect only on what is painted after it is invoked.

Comment: @c0der But I thought that the point at which you set the composite determines what is destination and what is source with destination being what is drawn before it is called and source being after. Otherwise if you set the composite at the beginning how do you specify which is which. For instance I already stated SrcIn doesn't work with my code, how should it be done so only the overlapping area is visible.

Comment: Add a an illustration of what you want to achieve